# How to set fixed colors for series legend?

Tags: telerik-reporting

I am using Telerik Reporting and creating reports with Report Designer.
What I want to do is set fixed colors for specific series elements.
For instance, in a monthly financial bar chart, if the series is Company, I want to set ElectricityCost as red and WaterCost as Blue all the time. The problem is that not every bar has all types of the cost, and for a specified time range, not all types will be included, which causes that the color legend varies.
I've tried some approaches but failed.
Is there anyone who knows how can I achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I find how to set the color for specific series.

The data points' color can be set by using the `Graph.Series.BarSeries.DataPointConditionalFormatting` property.
The legend markers' color can be set by using the `Graph.Series.BarSeries.LegendItem.MarkConditionalFormatting` property.

Besides the color, other styles can also be set so that for a certain series, the style will not change even no data is displayed after the filtering.